# android create oval inside custom drawable xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

i successfully created custom xml drawable file(image).i used it in my  layout
this is a my source code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#1Affffff" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#80ffffff" />


<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
    android:topRightRadius="4dip" />
```

now i want to add oval object in center position,but i don't know how to add it in center position.
does enyone knoes how i can add it in center position?
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an oval drawable like so

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/myColor" />
</shape>
```

**Option 1**

If you want to add an oval at the centre of that rectangle, just create another oval drawable load into a imageview and position the imageview at the centre of the imageview rendering the rectangle drawable

**Option 2**

First create bitmaps from the 2 drawables

```
Bitmap rectange = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rectangle);
Bitmap oval = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.oval);
```

then create canvas and draw the bitmaps, play with the input of the `drawBitmap` to get the positioning of your oval right.

```
// This bitmap will be the bitmap with oval in rectange after
// you finish drawing the canvas attached to it.
Bitmap ovalInRectangle = Bitmap.createBitmap(rectangle.getWidth, rectangle.getHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ovalInRectangle);
canvas.drawBitmap(rectangle, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(oval, 0,0,null);
return ovalInRectangle;
```

Comment: is it a possible to use both source code into one xml file?  @Bhargav

Comment: @user3863447 no if you want combine drawables (basically create a single bitmap to use in an imageview) then you need to do this programatically by loading the drawables into separate bitmaps and drawing them on canvas and create a new combined bitmap, ill add the code on how to do this to the answer and provide the necessary links too.